# Assign alert message while no internet in android app

Tags: android, alert

I need to show alert message while no internet connection.I have added the following code .But the alert box is not showing while no internet connection.

Here is the code:

```
 if (isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext()))
 {
       // Do whatever you want to do
 }
 else{

    try {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LiveChat.this);

         builder.setTitle("Message");
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to end the chat session?");
        // Add the buttons

        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }

        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
    System.out.println("alert="+e);
        }
 }
```

I have added this code in onCreate,

```
 public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {

        boolean value = false;
        ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
                || connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            value = true;
        }

        // Log.d ("1", Boolean.toString(value) );
        return value;
    }
```

When i turn off the internet connection the alert box is showing but while in the middle of my application the internet got slow down or lost connection i am not getting any alert

I need to check every second whether the internet available or not,if no connection i need to show the alert box.

Could somebody help me out @Thanks

Comment: How about using a countdown timer and checking the network connection each second?

Comment: @priya see my code might help u if u face any issue comment on that

Comment: @SKT yes..i have tried that too but receiving error something like Timer -1 ,

Comment: @priya You are saying that you have initialized your timer in your onFinish()  method of timer and started it again there, and you got this message?

Comment: @priya for every 5 secs you can see my code that will help u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked this code is working fine use this 
Create a inner **class** that will check on **every five seconds**

```
    private final long refreshDelay = 5 * 1000;
    SendHttpRequestThread sendHttpRequestThread; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        sendHttpRequestThread = new SendHttpRequestThread();
        sendHttpRequestThread.start();

    }

 class SendHttpRequestThread extends Thread {

        boolean sendHttpRequest;


        public SendHttpRequestThread() {

            sendHttpRequest = true;
        }

        public void stopSendingHttpRequest() {
            sendHttpRequest = false;
        }

        protected void onStop() {
            sendHttpRequestThread.stopSendingHttpRequest();
            super.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (sendHttpRequest) {
               boolean isConnected = isNetworkConnected();
                if(!isConnected){
                    showAlertDialog()
                }


                SystemClock.sleep(refreshDelay);
            }
        }
    }
```

check **network connection**

```
  private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
                  ConnectivityManager conManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                  NetworkInfo netInfo = conManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                  if (netInfo == null) {
                   // There are no active networks.
                   return false;
                  } else {
                   return true;
                  }
                 }
```

Show the **dialog**

```
 private void showAlertDialog() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        this.class);
                builder.setTitle("Error");
                builder.setMessage("No Network Connection").setCancelable(false)
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.error)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                error = "";
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but do you call this on a UI-Thread ? If you don't, it can be the problem.
You just have to put the code in :

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(
    new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            //Your code here
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code to check if internet is available or not.

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

if(!isOnline){
  //show alert
}else{
//continue with ur work
}
```

You will also need this permission in your Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: you can write it in a separate class say Internet, and call the above function in your code using if(!Internet.isOnline())

Answer (score 0):

```
//Method to check Internet Availability with Dialog box
public class CheckingInternet{
public static boolean isInternetAvailable(final Context context) {
//      boolean returnTemp = true;

        ConnectivityManager conManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo i = conManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if ((i == null) || (!i.isConnected()) || (!i.isAvailable())) {

        return false;
        }
        return true;
    }   

     public static  void showDialogForInternetConection(Context mContext){

         AlertDialog.Builder netNotAvailable=new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
         netNotAvailable.setMessage("Could not find an Internet connection. Please check your settings and try again.");
         netNotAvailable.setTitle("Attention");
         netNotAvailable.setIcon(R.drawable.attention);


         netNotAvailable.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        //  @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

            }
        });
         netNotAvailable.show();
     }

//With your Main Activity to show dialog
if(CheckingInternet.isInternetAvailable(mContext)){
//do Something
}
else{
CheckingInternet.showDialogForInternetConection(Context);
}
```